# How to detect if data.frame is grouped by dplyr from subfunction?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an R package where some functions are designed to be typically called within dplyr functions mutate or summarize.

```
newdata <- dplyr::mutate(group_by(olddata, col1), newcol = myfunc(col1))
```

However, sometimes users might forget to group their data before putting it into the mutate or summarize call.

```
newdata <- dplyr::mutate(olddata, newcol = myfunc(col1))
```

When the data frame is not grouped first, the package functions will produce largely nonsensical results. However, there won't be any errors or warnings per se, which could leave users uncertain about the cause of the issue.

I'd like to add a `Warning()` within the `myfunc` code when `myfunc` detects that the input data isn't coming from a grouped `data.frame`. However, I can't figure out how `myfunc` could detect if the data is coming from a grouped `data.frame`. It appears that `mutate` only passes a vector to `myfunc`, so both `dplyr::is.grouped_df` and `inherits(x, "grouped_df")` return false.

What I would like:

```
myfunc <- function(x) {if(comes.from.grouped.df) {print("grouped")} else {print("ungrouped")}}

mutate(olddata, newcol = myfunc(col1))
'ungrouped'

mutate(group_by(olddata, col1), newcol = myfunc(col1))
'grouped'
'grouped'
'grouped'
```

Comment: You may use `cur_data_all()` and then check the `is.grouped_df`

Comment: see `?group_data`, from dplyr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your function used within a specific context, and emit a warning if the data frame is not grouped, then you can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

myfunc <- function(x) {
  if(all(ls(envir = parent.frame()) == "~")) {
    ss <- sys.status()
    funcs <- sapply(ss$sys.calls, function(x) deparse(as.list(x)[[1]]))
    wf <- which(funcs == "mutate")
    if(length(wf) == 0) stop("`myfunc` must be called from inside `mutate`")
    wf <- max(wf)
    data <- eval(substitute(.data), ss$sys.frames[[wf]])
    if(!inherits(data, "grouped_df")) {
      warning("`myfunc` called on an ungrouped data frame / tibble.")
    }
    return(x^2)
  }
  stop("`myfunc` must be called from inside `mutate`")
}
```

Used outside `mutate`, we get an error:

```r
myfunc(1:10)
#> Error in myfunc(1:10): `myfunc` must be called from inside `mutate`
```

With an ungrouped data frame or tibble we get a warning:

```r
tibble(iris) %>% 
  mutate(x = myfunc(Sepal.Length))
#> Warning in myfunc(Sepal.Length): `myfunc` called on an ungrouped data frame /
#> tibble.
#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species     x
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa   26.0
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa   24.0
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa   22.1
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa   21.2
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa   25  
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa   29.2
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa   21.2
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa   25  
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa   19.4
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa   24.0
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

And it runs without complaint if the tibble is grouped:

```r
tibble(iris) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(x = myfunc(Sepal.Length))
#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species     x
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa   26.0
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa   24.0
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa   22.1
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa   21.2
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa   25  
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa   29.2
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa   21.2
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa   25  
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa   19.4
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa   24.0
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi there, this is really great, thanks!

I have one follow-up: how can this be modified to work when the input is a data.frame and not a tibble? As it is currently written, running: `mutate(iris, x = myfunc(Sepal.Length))` produces the error `object '.' not found`. Digging into it, the `eval(quote(.), parent.frame())` fails when the input is a data.frame and not a tibble, but `all(ls(envir = parent.frame()) == "~")` returns `TRUE` for a data.frame input. How can I modify this to support raw data.frame inputs? Sorry I don't understand it well enough to figure out myself how to do that.

Comment: @mikeblazanin it's got nothing to do with tibble versus data frame. The `quote(.)` only works if you pipe the data frame / tibble in. I have amended it to work either way now by using `quote(.data)`

Comment: Ahh gotcha, great! Although now when I run your edited function that uses `quote(.data)` with the third block of code: `tibble(iris) %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(x = myfunc(Sepal.Length))` it outputs the first error: `myfunc called on an ungrouped data frame / tibble.` Do you know why this might be the case?

Comment: @mikeblazanin my bad. It seems `.data` has to be evaluated in the exact system frame where `mutate` was called, otherwise it will interpret `.data` as the tidyverse `.data` pronoun (which may be a single group within a grouped tibble). I have modified the function to find the vorrect evaluation frame now.